# How can I set my service worker works to cloudflare's workers?

Tags: progressive-web-apps, service-worker, cloudflare

I'm using service worker with Workbox for PWA and it's working graete. The only problem that I'm facing is the preformance of the website. I think it's because of cloudflare therefor I decided to move my service worker to cloudflare's workers. Now I don't know how to do that. Is there anyone using cloudflare workers for PWA?

Comment: Service workers run on the client and can't be run on servers (or serverless).

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, it should be possible with the serverless model, and even with the new Cloudflare pages, using workers you want something like:

[2020-06-01 - Cloudflare Workers Developer Docs - Deploy a React app with create‑react‑app](https://developers.cloudflare.com/workers/tutorials/deploy-a-react-app-with-create-react-app)

Sort of an out of date post, dead links, but also goes over Worker PWAs:

[2018-11-23 - Cloudflare Blog - Serverless Progressive Web Apps using React with Cloudflare Workers](https://blog.cloudflare.com/serverless-pwa-react-cloudflare-workers/)

Comment: Is it all just about React apps?

Comment: It's definitely possible to use different languages to create service workers with Cloudflare. 

Some of the languages are JavaScript, Rust, C++, Python, etc. - for a complete list go here: https://blog.cloudflare.com/cloudflare-workers-announces-broad-language-support/ 

Also, per the Cloudflare blog "Cloudflare Workers are written in JavaScript against the service workers API, meaning they can use all the functionality offered by service workers" with the added benefit that they run in the edge of the Cloudflare network in between the user and the rest of the Internet, not client-side.